# Related to Event viewer application

Tags: security, command-line, microsoft-edge, event-viewer

## How do I enable audit logs for edge browser so that it can be seen in window logs -> security in event viewer application? Or is there any other way I could see "process information" ( as seen in security audit logs )for Microsoft edge browser ?

Process information relating to launching an application from edge browser in event logs with command line.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot view audit logs for edge browser in the Event viewer?
After checking, there are process information shown for Edge browser. Is it that you are referring to?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvBur.png